# DateTimeFormat annotation in spring time zone issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am having an issue to convert  string to date object. While converting it is picking the GMT timezone and getting changed into previous date. I want to ignore the timezone.If the string value is "03/12/2019" then it should the same date irrespective of the timezone.

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy") Date startDate
```

Any Suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solved it by using [Jodatime LocalDate](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) (which is without time zone by design):

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate
```

It can be converted to JDK Date by calling [toDate() method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate--).

You can also use for date pattern

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE, pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

[Dependency for maven](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/dependency-info.html):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

USe java.time.LocalDate instead of Date.

Answer (score 1):

Use java.time.LocalDate
LocalDate has no Time and therefore has no Timezone

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private LocalDate localDate;
```